# Facebook Secure Forms

Tags: facebook, forms, security, https, tabs

I am building some forms using the html input tabs in Facebook.
My form actions are post and insert linking to externally hosted php
function files.

The problem is, if the user isn't using Facebook's new https setting, a pop up
is shown with "un secure form"

Is there a why to provide a secure handler externally hosted or is this something
I would have go deeper into Facebook ap making with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook loads your app into an iframe (using POSTing a form).
When the user is using https with facebook they use the *Secure Canvas URL* property from the app settings, and when the user is not on secure browsing they use the *Canvas URL*.
Because of that, your page is not loaded from https but http, which is why that warning is shown to the user by the browser.

What you can do is to check when your page is loading which protocol is used and if it's not https then reload the page from https.
Something like (using [window.location object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)):

```
var location = window.location;
if (location.protocol != "https:") {
    window.location.href = "https://" + location.host + "/" + location.pathname + location.search
}
```

Or if you don't expect to have urls in your querystring you can simply replace:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("http", "https");
```

Comment: Hi nitzan, thanks for the reply, with the code above, where would i be placing that? Is this javascript for the canvas html itself that when opening it will redirect to https?

Comment: Yes, you can put that as the first script of your page, and then it will load up in https again if it's not already.